# Return different data type using only one method

Tags: apex, class, data, data-types, method

Is it possible to make an apex method wherein you can return different kind of data type (e.g. `Integer`, `String`, `Double`, etc.)?

Answer (score 9):

You can set return type of the Apex method to Object.

```
public Object returnVariousDataType(String dataType){
    //write something
    if(dataType == 'String'){
        // return String
        return 'this is a string';
    } else if(dataType == 'Integer'){
        // return Integer
        return 0;
    } else {
        // return other types
        return Date.today();
    }
}
```

And cast the return value to what you want when you invoke it.

```
Integer int = (Integer)returnVariousDataType('Integer');
```