# Overloading method return type in Apex

Tags: apex, method

Does Apex support method return type overloading ?

I mean can I have a method in a class that return different type depending on it's Inputs ?

Comment: [Return different data type using only one method](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92184/return-different-data-type-using-only-one-method)

Comment: @martin related Q but not the same, cause here the method has a different signature...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if the method signature is different you can have a different return type

In a class you can have

```
Integer add(Integer) 
String add(String)
```

But you can't have

```
Integer add(Integer)
String add(Integer)
```

A working example :

```
public class myClass {

  public Integer add(Integer num){
    return null;
  }

  public String add(String str){
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Typically the strategy is to use a more general type and cast it as the specific type, rather than arbitrarily changing the function parameters. A good example being `Database.query(String query)`, which always returns a `list<sObject>`

Comment: Yes, but I think that is more a JAVA way of thinking, if the method can return the specific type we need, why add a step of casting each time we invoke the method !

Comment: In case of Database.query the list of sObject types is not limited we can always create new types, but If we need to return a limited list of type example : Integer, String, Boolean  better to go with my example rather returning an Object type and cast it each invocation....